# What is a proper alternative to stop/break/kick an addiction?

Tags: synonyms, phraseology

With reference to someone trying to break an addiction, what is a word that properly means to stop the behavior? While "break" and "kick" would be understood, they are more informal than desired. "Stop" gives a connotation of something that is easy to do, which is not what I want to convey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Words like [suppress](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/suppress) and [fight](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fight) suggest more of a struggle against a certain behaviour, like in the case of addiction.

Also, [overcome](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overcome) is a word commonly used to represent "kicking" an addiction.

e.g:

> "He finally **overcame** his alcohol addiction after **fighting** for three years."

or

> "He **fought** to **overcome** his alcohol addiction and succeeded, after three years."

(Links to OED definitions)

Answer (score 0):

"*To surmount*" would be a good choice. It sounds formal. Hearing it used in daily conversation would definitely catch one's attention. It makes me think of "to summit", as in "to summit a very tall mountain".

> She surmounted her addiction.

Comment: Is your nom-de-stackexchange an ode to [this guy?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Red_Green_Show)

Comment: @GreenMatt nope. I just wanted to combine 2 simple words with an easily identifiable demarkation. Since "..dgr.." is never be found inside one whole word, a breakpoint naturally forms. I'll youtube the show. I might need a new handle...

Comment: @GreenMatt Thanks for the heads-up. I decided I need a new handle.